# Why does Majorana spin flipping occur?

Tags: atomic-physics, majorana-fermions, cold-atoms

Currently, I am reading the Nobel Lecture in Physics of 1997 by William D. Phillips. The lecture itself can be downloaded from this website: https://www.nobelprize.org/prizes/physics/1997/phillips/lecture/.  In one of the pages (215), he states that,

> "The (magnetic) zero field allows the magnetic moment of the atom to flip (often called Majorana flopping), so that the atom is in an untrapped spin state."

My question is this: Why does this spin flopping occur for an atom that is in a zero magnetic field point in a magnetic trap? Is it somehow related to an atom entering a superposition of down and up spin states?

Answer (score 1):

This question bothered me as well for some time. But I found an easy answer to this:
The spin is only well-defined within a magnetic field. It's connected to a magnetic moment being aligned to a magnetic field - either parallel, say spin up, are anti-parallel, say spin down.
The strength of the field does not matter to much here, unless, it becomes (close to) zero.
No magnetic field - no alignment.
The atom loses it's quantization axis and the spin state becomes random.

Why is the atom lost from the trap? I assume a quadrupole field here. The atom moves to a region of higher magnetic field eventually and becomes quantized again. Two things can happen:

- case 1: the atom has the spin which guarantees the trapping and stays in the trap.
- case 2: the atom has the wrong spin and is lost from the trap. This is the majorana loss. Eventually, every atom will be lost after some time if the probability of the atom being near the center of trap becomes large. And this is the case for cold atoms.