# Why is the Lamor frequency much faster than trapping frequency required in the magnetic trap?

Tags: atomic-physics, cold-atoms

I study the magnetic trapping recently. I met a problem. I consider the original quadruple magnetic trap. In the original quadruple magnetic trap, the magnetic vanishes at the center. The Majorana flips happens at the center.

If we want atoms move in the trap adiabatically, the Lamor frequency must be larger than the trapping frequency of the trap.

What does the 'adiabatically' mean and how come is the condition?

I saw this statement in my lecture note and other prof.'s lecture note but I have no idea why it is.

Comment: This is very related:   https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/729622/why-does-majorana-spin-flipping-occur/757344#757344

Comment: @kai90 Thank you for the reply!